# OpenMeetings not loading Office files (pptx, xlsx ...)

Tags: openoffice.org, jodconverter, openmeetings

I have Apache OpenMeetings installed and functioning properly.

I am not able to upload Office files to Whiteboard.

I succeeded to upload PDF files.

I installed JODconverter and updated the configuration to match the path.

I installed the OpenOffice to the machine adjust the "Path" environment variable and updated the configuration with the full path to the OpenOffice document.

but still not luck.

am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

From openmeetings administration panel, update the office.path configuration too. In this configuration, enter the path of your OpenOffice installation. This should fix the issue.